# How to generate tests based on data in nunit framework using C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

So i have this code:

```
[TestFixture]
[Category("MyTestSet")]
public class MyTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestCase12()
    {
        ExecuteTestCase(12);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestCase13()
    {
        ExecuteTestCase(13);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestCase14()
    {
        ExecuteTestCase(14);
    }
}
```

The ExecuteTestCase gets test parameters from my web server and executes the test case with these settings.

Each time i add a new test case parameters on my web server i need to add a new test in my C# code and pass the ID of test case parameters i have in my web server database and compile my code.

Is there any way to do it automatically? Like say, C# gets from my server ID's of all test case parameters and creates tests for them on the fly?

What is important, test cases change frequently. I was thinking about running all test cases in one test case on a loop, but than i'd be unable to run my test cases separately for example in Nunit  IDE.

So my question is: how to run multiple test cases depending on data i receive on run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TestCaseSource`attribute in order to get parameters from web service and have your test cases auto generated

```
[TestFixture]
[Category("MyTestSet")]
public class MyTests
{
    [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(GetTestParameters))]
    public void TestCase(int parameter)
    {
        ExecuteTestCase(parameter);
    }

    static int[] GetTestParameters()
    {
        //call web service and get parameters
        return new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
}
```

[documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5.9)

Comment: It seems interesting. When GetTestParameters() is executed? When test project is loaded, on compile time, when tests are loaded?

Comment: It is not executed on compile time. It is executed on test loading